# Does the framing under this plumbing leak require replacement?

Tags: water, wood, pipe, studs, rot

I found some rotted drywall and bottom trim near where my shut-off valve was installed. After tracking the leak, I found that it came from the water heater where copper connects to PVC. I'm going to call a plumber to fix that. I have questions about the water damage to the wood frame. It seems to be not too rotted. Thoughts if the wood stud and bottom plate is okay and just stained? Or if it needs to be repaired?

Thank you!

[image]

[image: WHITE POWDER IS FROM DRYWALL]

<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot push a nail or screwdriver into the wood by hand, the wood should be okay if it dries out.  Pushing it in, by more than 1/8 of an inch should be very hard.

The black stains/colour maybe should be tested for mould.  No way to tell from pictures.  If mould then it can be killed with common household chemicals/cleaners and dry air.

If the wood is soft for the nail/screwdriver test, then some replacement is the best course.